# Difference between android studio render and rendering on the emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator, android-linearlayout

My layouts must look like this. This is android studio render.[image: Screen render]

But when I load it on the emulator I get that:[image: Views on the emulator]

This problem is on all types of emulators. Also tested it on real Nexus 5 and it worked nice. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/content_layout" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/func_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/border_right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/function_layout_padding" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/graph_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="5">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<com.kripton.grapher.ui.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" 
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

First relative layout is needed because KeyboardView must be placed in it.

Then I get layouts and place views in them:

```
    graphLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph_layout);
    functionLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.func_layout);

    functionLayout.addView(addFunctionView);
    graphLayout.addView(mainGraphView);
```

There is no one more manupulation with layouts.

addFunctionView constructor:

```
    lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.verticalMargin = 0.0f;
    lp.horizontalMargin = 0.0f;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    this.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

graphView constructor:

```
    lp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Comment: Providing the code that performs the rendering would help solve the problem. Have you tried it on any other device besides Nexus 5?

Comment: @ikust just added code. Yes, I also tried it on one guy's HTC but doesn't remember model. And it works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Are You using the default values for the **activity_vertical_margin** and **activity_horizontal_margin** that were generated upon project creation with Android Studio?

If so, I think that deleting the **dimens.xml** file from **/main/res/values-w820dp** folder will help. That file contains:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Which adds extra horizontal padding on devices that have more than 820dp screen width. For some reason, Android Studio preview ignores that (I tried selecting Nexus 9 device for preview).

Comment: No, I don't use default values.

Comment: Did you implement **onMeasure()** in **addFunctionView** and **graphView** Views? If onMeasure() in those views is not limiting the width of the views somehow I'm not sure what else could be causing the problem.

Comment: No, **onMeasure()** isn't implemented. I think problem is not in code because on real devices it works fine though on nexus 5 and one of htc's model.